# IIS 10.0.10586.0 on Windows 10: Missing Deploy option

Tags: iis, web-deployment, iis-express, iis-8, webdeploy

I have installed IIS from control panel on Windows 10. Also Web Deploy 3.6 is already installed, maybe because I have installed visual studio 2013 ultimate and Visual Studio 2015.

Now I am trying to deploying a Web application on IIS. I have deployed it using "Web deploy package" publish method from Visual Studio. So from IIS, I am trying to import this package but Deploy option is missing under Default Web Site when I do right-click on it and hence that I cannot import application...

What's the problem?

Comment: I have solved it by uninstalling web deploy 3.6 and installing web deploy 3.5. After that I did a iisreset.

Comment: I have used Web Platform Installer 5.0

Comment: Post that as an answer and accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solution:

Using Web Platform Installer, uninstall web deploy 3.6 and install web deploy 3.5. After that an iisreset can be done.

Comment: I believe you should be able to achieve this also with WebDeploy 3.6. See my answer to a similar problem which I think has the same root cause (http://stackoverflow.com/a/41461305/5120854).

Comment: I was missing the iisreset step, once I did this it worked for me.